# How to send data from php file to android file and use service when new data was inserted?

Tags: php, android, sql-server, android-service

I want to use the function add proximity alerts and I have latitude and longitude. How can I said to the php file that when it gets new data it will send the data to an android file that will use the add proximity alerts function and will do notification to all the people who use the app and are in the 100 meter radius?

Comment: Do you have any code you can show us?  I don't understand what you mean by a "php file" and an "android file".  Are you trying to communicate from Android to a PHP web server?

Comment: Reading this again, it should like you are trying to create an Android application that will register with an internet web server the location of the device and then when that device comes within 100 meters of another registered device will send an alert to the user.

Comment: I have no idea what you are asking.. but based on a guess, you have an activity that you want to communicate with a service depending on the gelocation and distance for a particular target?

Answer (score 1):

All you need on the server-side is:

- Login
- ChangePosition => set's the current User(however you'll store the
  lat/long-information) to his new position.
- PersosnNearMe => Search your Records for persons near the user. I'm
  sure there are tons of php-libs or sql-scripts which can get all
  users within a certain radius.
   Save the information which
  persons are currently next to the user - you'll need it in
  "NeedsUpdate".
- NeedsUpdate: Return a simple bool if your android-phone needs to sync
  the list, based on the saved PersonsNearMe-information and a new
  request.

You can build this very easily as a RESTful-Server.
JSON is your friend here: http://php.net/manual/en/book.json.php

Building the RestfulClient is even easier: All you need to do is Login at start, querying "NeedsUpdate" every n seconds and then fire the alert-box if someone appears.
Finally you'll have to tell the server anytime you move with ChangePosition.

Comment: I can't find any function that find the people who are in the 100 meter radius. And why I need login?

Comment: Well you don't need login per se, but it's just something I thought you'll implement.
For the radius-thing: Check out this link: http://bit.ly/YKm3rY